# Редактирование структуры базы данных - логическая модель (Oracle SQL )

Tags: sql, база-данных, oracle, проектирование, er-diagram

Улица с несколькими Property_ID переходит в ведомство другого муниципалитета(Municipality_ID) . Необходимо отобразить это в базе данных, то есть чтобы все строки с адресами, которые содержат конкретную улицу, сменили Municipality_ID.

Проблема в том, что если использовать простую замену значения атрибута , не учитывается прeемственность в сущности Invoice .( То есть при простой замене атрибута, все исторические данные стираются и согласно базе данных, улица будто бы не меняла муниципалитет, а всегда находилась под ведомством нового)

Как это можно исправить? Допускается добавлять новые сущности и атрибуты.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Введите между Property и Municipality еще одну таблицу. Из Property поле муниципалитет исчезает и переходит в новую таблицу, со структурой:

```
 Property_id
 Municipality_id
 start_date
 end_date
 primary key (Property_id, Municipality_id, start_date)
```

Для порядка можно сделать триггер, контролирующий, что даты не пересекаются. Дату окончания у текущей записи можно оставлять NULL, хотя я в таких случаях предпочитаю использовать 01.01.3000, так поиск текущей записи гораздо проще (`SYSDATE between start_date and end_date`).

Правда мне ваша фраза *"чтобы все строки с адресами, которые содержат конкретную улицу, сменили Municipality_ID"* как то не понравилась, напрашивается еще одна сущность - "улица", которая собственно муниципалитету и принадлежит.